# Call Obj-C methods from html

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I am starting with hybrid development. I am trying to call an ojbective c method from my html button.

I created my Bridge class like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <JavaScriptCore/JSExport.h>

@protocol BSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEWProtocol <JSExport>

-(void) executeNativeMethod: (NSString*) operation json: (NSString*) jsonParams;

@end

@interface BSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEW : NSObject <BSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEWProtocol>

@end




#import "BSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEW.h"

@implementation BSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEW

-(void)executeNativeMethod:(NSString *)operation json:(NSString *)jsonParams{

}

@end
```

Then, in my webview I did this:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [self showLoadingHUD];
    // get JSContext from UIWebView instance
    JSContext *jsContext = [webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

    [jsContext setObject:_bSMThirdPartyIntegrationsBridgeNEW.self forKeyedSubscript:@"NativeMethods"];

    // enable error logging
    [jsContext setExceptionHandler:^(JSContext *context, JSValue *value) {
        NSLog(@"WEB JS: %@", value);
    }];
}
```

Finally, my html file contains:

```
<div>
    <button onclick="NativeMethods.executeNativeMethod('sign', '')">Sign</button>
</div>
```

Why my executeNativeMethod is not called?

Thanks